# How to create disk partitions without unmounting the disk?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, usb, windows-10, unmount

So, I want to create a partition of 400 GB of my 1 TB HDD to install Windows 10 on it. I could usually use FDisk but I believe it requires me to have unmounted the disk. I could create a bootable USB and then create the partition, but I already have Windows 10 ready to install on my USB and I can not overwrite that with Ubuntu as I already troubled by friend to make me the Windows USB (I could do it myself if someone were to suggest a good software. WoeUSB & UNetBootin did not work for me and Rufus is only avalible on Windows). Another thing I could do was go to the Windows installation thingy and open cmd then use diskpart to make the partitions, though that is not an option either because it gives me this "No more free extent could b e found". Any help is appreciated, if you want clearification ask in the comments. English is not my first language so if you could edit this to correct my spelling and grammar I would really appreciate it.

TLDR: Need to make a disk partition without unmounting, can not use a bootable USB

Solution: For anyone else who might be searching about this. You cant do it.

Comment: Borrow another USB from a different friend.

Comment: It's not possible. If you don't unmount the disk, you will lose all data. I suggest you install MS Windows in a virtual machine.

Comment: You can create partitions only in unallocated space. Unallocated space is never mounted. It is always possible to create a partition in the unallocated space. I guess your problem is that you want to create a partition of 400 GB size and the unallocated space is not big enough. Thus you need to resize other  already existing partitions first. These partitions indeed may need to be unmounted to resize them.

Comment: @user535733 I would, but I don't have any.

Comment: You seem to be trying to avoid a fundamental requirement (partitions must be unmounted when edited) in a very risky activity (partitioning). This is how folks destroy their systems and lose all of their data. It is a very unwise area for new-user experimentation. You cannot patch a bicycle tire while riding upon it, no matter how much you "need" to. Consider installing Windows to a VM instead, or just find a way to obtain another USB stick. USB sticks are neither expensive nor rare. It's also an opportunity to make new friends.

Answer (score 0):

Mounted partitions are actively in use by the system.  It is extremely likely that if you go messing around with your partitions while the system is running that you will lose your data/working system unless you were using something like LVM on an already installed system.  For example, Gparted will show that a mounted partition is locked by displaying a small key icon next to it and not allowing you to make changes to it.

What is currently on the 1TB HDD?  Is it blank?

Comment: The HDD has Ubuntu 20.04 installed on it. So, is there no way?

Comment: I'd backup my data, wipe the drive and install Windows.  Then put Ubuntu on a USB drive and boot it.  From the live environment resize the Windows partition and then use the free space to install Ubuntu.  The Ubuntu installer should pickup Windows and add it to Grub.  You should then have a dual boot system up and running.

Answer (score 0):

*(Wanted to add this as a comment, but I can't)*

If anyone else having a similar problem should come across this, this might have been a good solution too:

[How to modify partitions without a live USB/CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314402/how-to-modify-partitions-without-a-live-usb-cd/1314403)

And here is a detailed guide on how to boot (other) ISO files from hard drive: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

It is even possible to use this method for installing Ubuntu without a USB drive or DVD (as long as GRUB is present and working)

(Hope it may be useful for somebody else)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1176440)

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I don't think I will ever have enough "reputation" to comment as this site is quite confusing and frustrating for new users. - I would have posted this in the linked topic, but again I can't ^-^ So I'll rather quit than spend hours on this site until it will allow me to write a comment... (This can be moved whereever it seems suitable) (PS: I think my answer actually does provide a solution for the original "I can not use a bootable USB" problem, although the OP probably found some other way by now)